# Running tests using firefox using selenium grid

Tags: vb.net, testing, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I have tests written in vb.net and selenium. I configured selenium grid So I may run several dll's together using selenium grid. Using the following wont make the session run.

```
using selenium.Setup("localhost", 4444, "*chrome C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", My.Settings.URL)

It is throwing the following error (TestFixtureSetUp):
SetUp : Selenium.SeleniumException : ERROR: Could not retrieve a new session
```

I have 3 available RC with firefox, chrome and iexplore environment. Using iexplore works fine and it executes tests fine but when using firefox it wont retrieve the session. Please guide what I am doing wrong here.

edit 1: Using selenium-grid-1.0.8 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the above problem of makine rc work with grid by passing the seleniumProtocol=Selenium parameters to command

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role rc -hubHost localhost -browser browserName=*firefox,maxInstances=3,platform=WINDOWS,seleniumProtocol=Selenium
```

In test use the following

```
selenium.Setup("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", URL)
```

hope it will help someone